# Navigation Drawer for Multiple Activity

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I was having some problem when trying to make my navigation drawer in Android accessible from all Activity. I have a NavigationDrawer.java:

```
public class NavigationDrawer extends Activity {

static Context context;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ExpandableListView mDrawerList;
private LinearLayout navDrawerView;
CustomExpandAdapter customAdapter;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mEventSelection;
private String[] mProfileSelection;
private int selectedPosition;
List<SampleTO> listParent;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
ArrayList<Event> newsFeedList = new ArrayList<Event>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    context = this;
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    navDrawerView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.navDrawerView);
    mEventSelection = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.event_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.nav_left_drawer);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);

    listParent = new ArrayList<SampleTO>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    listParent.add(new SampleTO(getString(R.string.eventDrawer),
            R.drawable.event));

    listDataChild.put(getString(R.string.eventDrawer),
            Arrays.asList(mEventSelection));

    customAdapter = new CustomExpandAdapter(this, listParent, listDataChild);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    mDrawerList.setChoiceMode(ExpandableListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

// Navigation drawer with sub menu goes here
public void selectItem(int groupPosition, int position) {
    selectedPosition = position;
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navDrawerView);
    if (groupPosition == 0) {
        switch (selectedPosition) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
    }
    // Navigation item for event
    else if (groupPosition == 3) {
        switch (selectedPosition) {
        case 0:
            Intent eventMain = new Intent(context, EventMain.class);
            context.startActivity(eventMain);
            break;
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(NavigationDrawer.this, "Analyze Event",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }
    }
    setTitle(mEventSelection[selectedPosition]);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mDrawerList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {
            int index = parent.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView
                    .getPackedPositionForGroup(groupPosition));
            parent.setItemChecked(index, true);

            String parentTitle = ((SampleTO) customAdapter
                    .getGroup(groupPosition)).getTitle();

            if (parentTitle.equals(getString(R.string.amenityDrawer))) {
                Toast.makeText(NavigationDrawer.this, "Amenity",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                setTitle(parentTitle);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navDrawerView);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    mDrawerList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            int index = parent.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView
                    .getPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition));
            parent.setItemChecked(index, true);
            selectItem(groupPosition, childPosition);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(navDrawerView);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

And then I navigate to my second class which is EventMain.java when the sub item from navigation drawer is selected:

```
public class EventMain extends NavigationDrawer {
public static MapView mMapView = null;
ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer tileLayer;
LocationManager locationManager;
public static GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = null;
public static Callout callout;

private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;
private Calendar c;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 2;

private LinearLayout legendDiv, llNewsFeed, llSearch;
private ListView listview;
private Button btnNewsFeed, btnSearchAddr, btnLegends;
private EditText searchAddrET;
private ImageView ivEventGuide;

public static LinearLayout directionDiv;
public static TextView tvDirection, tvDirectionTitle, tvSearchTitle;
static EventController eventCtrl = new EventController();
static Event eventModel = new Event();

private ListAdapter mAdapter;
ArrayList<Event> newsFeedList = new ArrayList<Event>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ArcGISRuntime.setClientId("UkIVSWzquykoxCMG");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.event_main);
    context = this;
}
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.event_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

It did shows the navigation drawer icon at the EventMain.java. However, when I try to expand it, it does not work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

The xml layout of my EventMain:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/event_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.esri.android.map.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        initExtent="21801.3, 25801.0, 33218.7, 44830.0" >
    </com.esri.android.map.MapView>

    //Other linear and relative layouts
 </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Any ideas? Because I cannot figure it out :(

Comment: Does the `NavigationDrawer` Activity work on its own?

Comment: @MikeM. Yeah, it works on the first page which is NavigationDrawer.java. But then when I switched to my second page which is EventMain.java after selecting item from nav drawer, the drawer stopped working

Comment: I'm kinda stumped. That seems as though it should work fine. Can you drag the Drawer open in `EventMain`? Does the Home Button react to the click? That is, does it highlight when you press it?

Comment: Nope, I could not open up the drawer. And yeah it did highlight when I press it. Let me post the xml layout of the EventMain. Was thinking could it be the layout overlap on top of the navigation drawer?

Comment: Oh, is that not the entire `EventMain` class?

Comment: @MikeM. Inside the EventMain class, I just do like the normally what we did for a new Intent. Check my edited EventMain.java :)

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.event_main);` <== Right there. That's replacing your DrawerLayout, so `EventMain`, as is, does not have a Drawer, which is why it's not opening.

Comment: @MikeM. But then for my EventMain itself has a layout so I could not use the layout of navigationdrawer and I thought I am extending from the NavigationDrawer?

Comment: Oh, we can probably figure something out. Post your `main` layout, then we should head to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66909/discussion-between-mike-m-and-denise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `EventMain`'s `onCreate()` method, `setContentView()` is being called after the call to the `super.onCreate()` method. This is causing the `DrawerLayout` set in the base class, `NavigationDrawer`, to be replaced, effectively removing the Drawer. To prevent this, we ensure the `DrawerLayout` has the standard container `FrameLayout` for main content, and inflate `EventMain`'s layout into that.

The base Activity's layout, `main.xml`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/event_frame" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        ...

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And in the Activity subclass, `EventMain`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.event_frame);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.event_main, content, true);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I saw you figured out the layout problem. Nice job! I hadn't even noticed that.

Comment: Thanks :) By the way, let's say I got another class with tabs extends from FragmentActivity instead of NavigationDrawer, can I do the same as above to show the navigation drawer on that page? Also, let's say next time I will have more activity, so basically I just declared the frame layout one after each other in the main.xml will do?

Comment: If you change `NavigationDrawer` to extend FragmentActivity, then, yeah, your tabs Activity could extend that. Just a note, though: I'm not sure how easy it is to implement tabs with a DrawerLayout. I've not done it, but I see enough questions about it pop up on SO to make me think there's some sort of catch to it.